# Interceptor Error Restangular its run 2 times

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I have this interceptor for errors 401 in restangular:

```
Restangular.setErrorInterceptor(function(response, deferred, responseHandler) {
             if(response.status === 401) {
                 ServiceLocalStorageLogin.removeTokenSession();
                 ServiceLocalStorageLogin.removeToken();
                 location.href="#/";

                 return false; // error handled
             }

            return true; // error not handled
        });
```

The problem is, I want to put inside the "if" a message, but when i have in my controller 2 or more services, all these services give you 401 error and the "if" validator runs 2 or more times, and show me the message 2 or more times.

How I do to show the message 1 time ? or How runs the interceptor 401 1 time ?

Any help.

Comment: Where is this being called? Provide a [mcve]

Comment: I have in my controller.js 2 services that are executed by default and these give error 401.

Comment: that doesn't answer where you are calling `Restangular.setErrorInterceptor()`

Comment: also if you make 2 requests you expect 2 alerts . Only way to get around it is wrapping multiple requests in a promise array and using a catch

Comment: I call Restangular.setErrorInterceptor() on the "run" in my app.module.js